# Write the vectors u, v, w, z in terms of a and b.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> Write the vectors $u, v, w, z$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

[image]

I'm unsure of how to do this.. If someone could give me an example of one being done I'm almost positive I could mimic it and figure out the rest

Comment: The point where all vectors start is the $(0,0)$ of the space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the points $u,v,w,z$ in relation of the coordinates and then get a linear combination of $a,b$ such that is equal to them. $u=(0,3)$, $v=(-2,1)$, $w=(1,4)$, $z=(3,0)$. Here is an example:

$$
2a-b=2(1,1)-(-1,2)=(2,2)+(1,-2)=(3,0)=z
$$

The other ones are here in case you want to try it before check an answer

> $$ -a+b=-(1,1)+(-1,2)=(-1,-1)+(-1,2)=(-2,1)=v $$
>  $$ 2a+b=2(1,1)+(-1,2)=(2,2)+(-1,2)=(1,4)=w $$
>  $$ a+b=(1,1)+(-1,2)=(1,1)+(-1,+2)=(0,3)=u $$

Comment: Thank you, greatly explained. Also thank you for hiding the answers so that I could do that for myself before checking. Great explanation! Great!

Comment: Thanks :-). Sorry by editing it like four or five times, but I wanted it to be totally clear.

Answer (score 1):

Simply draw multiples of $a$'s and $b$'s so that you get a path to the other vectors, in this way you'll have their combination. I think this is a purely drawing-geometrical exercise. For example if you add $b$ on $a$, you get $u$, as you move one left and two above. Adding $a$ to $a$ and then $b$ to this, you get $w$ and so on.

- $a$ = one right, one above (call it) $(1,1)$
- $b$ = one left, two above (call it) $(-1,2)$

so we have $2*a + b = (2-1,2+2)=(1,4)=w$

Remember that for some of them you'll have to add negative $a$'s or negative $b$'s, which you do by simply writing the vector in the same direction but opposite sense.

For example we have $ b +(-a) = v $